Gibbs measure as stationary distribution of SDEs
I have been trying to understand how one can mathematically explain some of the results from statistical mechanics, especially regarding certain distributions like the Gibbs distribution. It would be ideal if we could derive a SDE related to physical phenomena such that the Gibbs distribution is its limiting distribution. I think this makes the Gibbs measure look more 'natural'. I had previously asked a related question on MO: Convergence to unique stationary distribution for SDEs and Markov processes.
So, I was quite excited when I recently found this question on MSE: How to show that the Gibbs measure is a stationary distribution of the following SDE?.
The MSE question says:

I try to get the stationary distribution $$\pi=e^{-H(x)}dx/Z$$ and
$Z=\int e^{-H(x)}dx$ called Gibbs measure for the following SDE:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:ld}
     dX_t=-\nabla H(X_t)dt+\sqrt{2}dB_t, \, X_0=x, \end{equation} where $H(t)$ is the potential function on $R^n$.
Let $P_t$ be the semi-groups of $X_t$ that is
$P_tf(x)=E[f(X_t)|X_0=x]$ for $t>0$ and smooth functions $f$.
How to verify this Gibbs measure is the stationary distribution with
respect to the semi-group $P_t$? That means for any smooth functions
$f$
$$ \pi(P_t f)=\pi(f)=\int f d\pi $$

I find this question very interesting because it aligns with many of the topics I care about: a SDE involving the energy function $H(x)$, with the Gibbs distribution as its stationary distribution. However, this question has remained unanswered for over two years.
Here are the questions I am particularly concerned with:

Is this conclusion correct? It seems natural to me. I feel that the noise term, with the constant $\sqrt{2}$, must be related to the coefficient of $H(x)$ in the exponential of the Gibbs distribution. In other words, the size of the noise determines the "temperature" of the Gibbs distribution.

While the equation involves the energy function $H(x)$, it is a gradient flow rather than a Hamiltonian equation, which is more common in physical systems. I'm curious whether there are other forms of SDEs that also have the Gibbs distribution as their stationary distribution. Are there any textbooks on SDEs that specifically discuss these types of equations?

Similarly, I wonder whether this particular SDE has any special significance or applications. What kinds of models can be described by this equation, particularly in the context of statistical mechanics? For instance, could one derive such an SDE by approximating the Hamiltonian equations of motion for a system with a large number of particles? Another way of obtaining the Gibbs distribution is via the Boltzmann equation, but I have always struggled to fully understand the derivation of the Boltzmann equation. Could there be a connection between that derivation and this SDE?



So first, your equation is generally known as the Langevin dynamics. For Q1, the $\sqrt{2}$ is an artefact of the difference between the probabilists and the analysts definitions of the Laplacian (as the generator of the Brownian motion). Informally, changing the temperature changes the smoothness of the stationary distribution, e.g. the normalization constant.
Under suitable conditions on $H$ and stationary (Gibbs) distributions, one can derive exponential convergence of a starting distribution to the limiting distribution. Some arguments (answer to Q2) can be found in

Log-concave sampling, Chewi
Analysis aand geometry of Markov diffusion operators, Bakry, Gentil, Ledoux

The first studies the exact equation of your form, e.g. gradient-driven drifts, and comes from a discretization/implementation perspective. The second is more general.
For a partial answer to Q3: I'm not as familiar with statistical physics, but there is a generalization called the mean-field Langevin dynamics that is the limit of interacting particle systems. In the setting I'm familiar with, they show up in infinite-width neural networks. It solves a Langevin dynamics with non-linear drift, and additionally corresponds to a non-linear Fokker-Planck equation. You can find more information in the following papers

Mean-field Langevin dynamics and energy landscape of neural
networks
Mean-field Langevin dynamics:
exponential convergence and annealing
Convex analysis of the mean-field Langevin dynamics


Here is some answers for your first two questions.
answer to Q1
Yes,the SDE
$${\rm d}U_t= - H'(U_t) {\rm d}t+\sqrt {2} \, {\rm d} B_t,$$
has the following Fokker-Plank equation (i.e. the pde satisfied by its its density):
$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial t}(u, t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \left(H'(u) \, p(u, t) + \frac{\partial p}{\partial u}(u, t) \right). $$
However, we see that the stationary solution i.e. $p_{t}=0$ satisfies the ODE
$$H'(u) \, p(u) + \frac{\partial p}{\partial u}(u)=0$$
i.e.
$$p(u)=cexp(-H(u)).$$
answer to Q2
Yes, there is a large literature on this topic going under the name "invariant measures".

(Stochastic Modelling and Applied Probability 66) Rafail Khasminskii (auth.)  Stochastic Stability of Differential Equations.
"Long-time dynamics of stochastic differential equations"
"Ergodicity and speed of convergence to equilibrium for diffusion processes"
"Convergence of Markov Processes" by Hairer
"Existence and uniqueness of martingale solutions for SDEs with rough or degenerate coefficients".
-"An SDE perspective on stochastic convex optimization"
"Invariant Distributions for Singular Stochastic Differential Equations"
-some more references listed in this presentation

